# Formula R1C1 issues using IF

Tags: vba, if-statement

this is new for me. I have an issue trying to run a formula in VBA using IF.

The idea is to include in AR3 column a modification date when in C3 there contains information.

This is what I wrote:

```
Range("AR3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]="";"";IF(RC[-44]="";NOW();RC[-44])"
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: change semicolon to comma and escape quotes: `"=IF(RC[-3]="""","""",IF(RC[-44]="""",NOW(),RC[-44])" `

Comment: Hi simoco, unfortunately this is still not working :-(

Comment: it is still highlighted in yellow this row and when I run the macro it shows the error. any idea?

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things are not right with your formula:

- You need to escape the double quotes (with double quotes... so four in total)
- You are missing a closing parenthesis
- This is optional, but you don't need to select the range

You can use the following corrected statement:

```
Range("AR3").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]="""","""",IF(RC[-44]="""",NOW(),RC[-44]))"
```

Next time you run into this kind of trouble, just use the macro recorder: click on "Record macro", and enter your formula. Plus, you can always change the display in Excel to the R1C1 Reference style (Options > Formulas > R1C1 reference style) when that is helpful (Personally I've mapped this change to a shortcut key combination so I can easily get column numbers if needed)

Comment: I had a similar problem. Checked the parenthesis etc but in the end, the semicolons were the perpetrator!